How To Add Cookie A Header To A Websocket Request In ReactJS (Like Postman Does)
To Mods: I've read every other relevant question on SO before posting this. Historically, the solution has been 'just forget about cookies and pass auth in utm params', but that answer is not an option in my case and, moreover, Postman Desktop is able to successfully append the header I need to connect to the Five9 websocket endpoint.
Hi all, I'm trying to replicate a websocket connection request that Postman Desktop is able to establish effortlessly. In order to establish the connection there, all I do is set the url to wss://app-atl.five9.com/appsvcs/ws?farmId=xxxxxxx and add a Header Key of Cookie with a value of Authorization=Bearer-xxxxxx, these values are passed back from an original login event. From here, I press connect and voilà, the cookie Header is appended to the websocket request, and the connection is established.
But, when I try to do this using the standard reactJS Websocket Library I absolutely cannot get this cookie header to pass. I've tried just about every solution I could find online up until this point, but no dice. Here is my current code:
  const setNewCookies = async () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  console.log("settings cookies");
    const cookiePath = "/";
    const domain = "five9.com";
    const authToken = five9WebSocketData["tokenId"];
    const sessionId = five9WebSocketData["sessionId"];
    const farmId = five9WebSocketData["context"]?.["farmId"] ?? 0;
    const cookieString = `Authorization=Bearer-${authToken}; farmId=${farmId}; path=${cookiePath}; domain=${domain}; sessionId=${sessionId}`;
    document.cookie = cookieString;
    resolve();
})

}
That code handles setting document cookies (I placed them in a separate const to address a suspicion that the cookies were not being set by the time the WS connection request was made... (made no difference)
And then this is the code that is supposed to create the WS Connection:
useEffect(()=>{
    const connectWebSocket = async () => {
      if (five9WebSocketData) {
        await setNewCookies();
        const farmId = five9WebSocketData["context"]?.["farmId"] ?? 0;
        const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://app-atl.five9.com/appsvcs/ws?farmId=${farmId}`);
  
        // Event listener for WebSocket open
        ws.onopen = () => {
          console.log('WebSocket connected');
        };
  
        // Event listener for WebSocket messages
        ws.onmessage = (event) => {
          console.log('Message received:', event.data);
          setMessage(event.data);
        };
  
        // Event listener for WebSocket close
        ws.onclose = () => {
          console.log('WebSocket disconnected');
        };
  
        // Set the WebSocket instance in state
        setSocket(ws);
      }
    };
  
    connectWebSocket();
  },[five9WebSocketData]);

This attempts to establish the connection but, considering no Cookie headers are appended, it fails.
Also important to note, I have already tried using the undocumented third parameter to the websocket API to no avail like so:
new WebSocket(wss://app-atl.five9.com/appsvcs/ws?farmId=${farmId}, 'GET', {Cookie: 'Authorization=xxxx'});
I've also tried declaring the entire third param as an object outside of this, which failed as well.
When I inspect the cookies set in the browser, I see the following:

To me (and PLEASE correct me if I am wrong here as I'm admittedly a bit fuzzy in the area of cross domain cookie sharing) this looks fine. The name is correct, value is godo, as is the domain, http only, secure, and SameSite is None.
I've already burned a day and a half trying to replicate the behavior that Postman does so effortlessly, and am at a loss for what to try next, any ideas would be appreciated and likely helpful for others.
